# How to arrange the statement accordingly in dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

a function which gives statements of commentary, the problem is they contain `<br> and </br>` tags, I want to arrange these in a new line

```
from pycricbuzz import Cricbuzz
c = Cricbuzz()
commentary1 = []
current_game3 = {}
matches = c.matches()
for match in matches:
    if(match['mchstate'] != 'nextlive'):
            col= (c.commentary(match['id']))
            for my_str in col['commentary']:
                current_game3[ "commentary2"] = my_str
                commentary1.append(current_game3)
                current_game3 = {}
                print(commentary1)
```

when I print  this  I get output as below

```
{'commentary2': 'Preview by Tristan Lavalette<br/><br/>The Twenty20 tri-series decider between Australia and New Zealand is set to finish with a bang at the tiny Eden Park on Wednesday (February 21), as another bout of belligerent batting is expected in Auckland.<br/><br/>In a preview of the final, the teams clashed at Eden Park last Friday and produced a run-fest with the rampaging Australia successfully chasing down a record target of 244. The unbeaten Australia head into the final as favourites after a dazzling campaign from their new look side brimming with in-form Big Bash League players and headed by skipper David Warner, whose inventive captaincy has been inspirational.<br/><br/>Astoundingly, Australia is on the brink of leapfrogging into the No.1 T20 ranking having started the tournament a lowly No.7. A victory would be their sixth straight in the format equalling their best ever streak.<br/><br/>Australia\'s hard-hitting batting has relished chasing in every match and New Zealand\'s brains trust might deeply consider bowling first if skipper Kane Williamson wins the toss. Packed with firepower, Australia ooze with match-winners and chased down the record target with relative ease, confirming their penchant to chase. At the comically miniature Eden Park ground, Australia\'s powerful batting will be confident no matter the situation of the match.<br/><br/>Of course, the beleaguered bowlers aren\'t quite as cheery after copping a flogging last start especially to New Zealand dynamo Martin Guptill. Much like their counterparts, the Black Caps boast a high-octane batting order that has been inconsistent throughout the tournament but, ominously, has the artillery to spearhead New Zealand to a triumph.<br/><br/>Australia\'s attack has been settled throughout the tri-series but selectors might be tempted to tweak it in a bid to ruffle the Black Caps. Legspinner Adam Zampa could be given a call-up on the wearing pitch - the same one used for Friday\'s encounter - which is set to be helpful for spin.<br/><br/>If Zampa gets the nod, Australia will be faced with a dilemma of culling one of their frontline quicks of Billy Stanlake, Kane Richardson and Andrew Tye, who have each starred at various stages during the tri-series. Australia\'s fresh team has matured quickly but the pressure will be intensified in an away final amid an electrifying atmosphere.<br/><br/>Even they though endured a rocky tournament yielding just one win, New Zealand squeaked past England to reach the decider but will need to lift their game if they are to cause an upset. The Black Caps have been unable to consistently recapture their best after coming into the tri-series ranked No. 2 in the world.<br/><br/>New Zealand\'s eclectic bowling has struggled although the spin combination of Mitchell Santner and Ish Sodhi could prove a handful on this deck. For such a composed and experienced team, New Zealand has looked occasionally rattled having agonisingly lost consecutive matches.<br/><br/>Despite their struggles, New Zealand know one strong performance is enough for them to claim glory in front of their parochial home crowd desperate for some revelry.<br/><br/>With all to play for, the stage is set for a memorably entertaining finish for this inaugural tri-series tournament.<br/><br/>When: Wednesday, February 21, 2018; 7PM local, 11.30AM IST<br/><br/>Where: Eden Park, Auckland<br/><br/>What to expect: There is a chance of showers intervening. Once again, there should be plenty of runs on offer on the small ground although the pitch is tipped to produce some turn.<br/><br/>Team News<br/><br/>New Zealand: Despite agonisingly losing their last couple of games, New Zealand are set to stick with the same line-up.<br/><br/>Probable XI: Martin Guptill, Colin Munro, Kane Williamson (c), Colin de Grandhomme, Mark Chapman, Ross Taylor, Tim Seifert (wk), Mitchell Santner, Tim Southee, Ish Sodhi, Trent Boult<br/><br/>Australia: Zampa could be in line to play with the pitch possibly providing some turn. However, a red hot Australia may not want to disturb a winning combination.<br/><br/>Probable XI: David Warner, D\'Arcy Short, Chris Lynn, Glenn Maxwell, Aaron Finch, Marcus Stoinis, Alex Carey (wk), Ashton Agar, Kane Richardson, Andrew Tye, Billy Stanlake<br/><br/>Did you know<br/><br/>- Australia\'s greatest winning streak in T20Is is their six straight victories at the 2010 World T20 before losing the final to England<br/><br/>- David Warner has won 8 of 9 as T20 captain. The best record overall - minimum 10 matches - is Pakistan\'s Sarfraz Ahmed\'s 14 wins from 17 matches<br/><br/>- New Zealand have lost their last four T20I matches at Eden Park<br/><br/>What they said<br/><br/>"We\'ve had three pretty close T20 games, Australia batting exceptionally well at Eden Park and chasing down a score that was pretty formidable. But you\'ve got to be in the final and give yourself a chance" - Mike Hesson, the New Zealand coach.<br/><br/>"You\'ve just got to find a way to get one or two wickets in the first six (overs), it\'s as simple as that" - David Warner, the Australia captain, said about bowling at the tiny Eden Park.'},
```

I want to arrange like this

```
Preview by Tristan Lavalette
The Twenty20 tri-series decider between Australia and New Zealand is set to finish with a bang at the tiny Eden Park on Wednesday (February 21), as another bout of belligerent batting is expected in Auckland.
In a preview of the final, the teams clashed at Eden Park last Friday and produced a run-fest with the rampaging Australia successfully chasing down a record target of 244. The unbeaten Australia head into the final as favourites after a dazzling campaign from their new look side brimming with in-form Big Bash League players and headed by skipper David Warner, whose inventive captaincy has been inspirational.
Astoundingly, Australia is on the brink of leapfrogging into the No.1 T20 ranking having started the tournament a lowly No.7. A victory would be their sixth straight in the format equalling their best ever streak.<br/><br/>Australia\'s hard-hitting batting has relished chasing in every match and New Zealand\'s brains trust might deeply consider bowling first if skipper Kane Williamson wins the toss. Packed with firepower, Australia ooze with match-winners and chased down the record target with relative ease, confirming their penchant to chase. At the comically miniature Eden Park ground, Australia\'s powerful batting will be confident no matter the situation of the match.
Of course, the beleaguered bowlers aren\'t quite as cheery after copping a flogging last start especially to New Zealand dynamo Martin Guptill. Much like their counterparts, the Black Caps boast a high-octane batting order that has been inconsistent throughout the tournament but, ominously, has the artillery to spearhead New Zealand to a triumph.
Australia\'s attack has been settled throughout the tri-series but selectors might be tempted to tweak it in a bid to ruffle the Black Caps. Legspinner Adam Zampa could be given a call-up on the wearing pitch - the same one used for Friday\'s encounter - which is set to be helpful for spin.
If Zampa gets the nod, Australia will be faced with a dilemma of culling one of their frontline quicks of Billy Stanlake, Kane Richardson and Andrew Tye, who have each starred at various stages during the tri-series. Australia\'s fresh team has matured quickly but the pressure will be intensified in an away final amid an electrifying atmosphere.
Even they though endured a rocky tournament yielding just one win, New Zealand squeaked past England to reach the decider but will need to lift their game if they are to cause an upset. The Black Caps have been unable to consistently recapture their best after coming into the tri-series ranked No. 2 in the world.
New Zealand\'s eclectic bowling has struggled although the spin combination of Mitchell Santner and Ish Sodhi could prove a handful on this deck. For such a composed and experienced team, New Zealand has looked occasionally rattled having agonizingly lost consecutive matches.
Despite their struggles, New Zealand knows one strong performance is enough for them to claim glory in front of their parochial home crowd desperate for some revelry.
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to print each commentary dictionary in the commentary1 list, you want to replace the

```
print(commentary1)
```

line with

```
print("\n".join([" ".join(i.values()).replace("<br/><br/>", "\n") for i in commentary1]))
```

That will take all the dictionaries in the commentary1 list, then take all of their values, append them with a space, replace the `<br/><br/>` tags with \n, then join them.

Comment: I get a error using this  print(" ".join(commentary1.values()).replace("<br/><br/>", "\n"))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: @nikhil is commentary1 a list or a dictionary? What your printed is a dictionary, not a list

Comment: yeah it is list of dictionary sorry for that not mentioning

Comment: commentary1 = [] where I append the values to

Comment: @nikhil Fixed it.

Comment: what is a in that?

Comment: @nikhil It is commentary1, forgot to change that from where I was making it

Comment: when I did this ("\n".join([" ".join(i.values()).replace("<br/><br/>", "\n") for i in all])).append(current_game3)

Comment: I get TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

Comment: is there any way possible to edit before appending to commentary1?

Comment: @nikhil Commentary1 is a list. You can edit dictionaries and then append them to it. ("\n".join([" ".join(i.values()).replace("<br/><br/>", "\n") for i in all])) is a string. You can't append dictionaries to it.

Comment: Yeah I got that error problem is I rendering the value of edited dictionary to template not only I want to print the value

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
from pycricbuzz import Cricbuzz

c = Cricbuzz()
commentary1 = []
current_game3 = {}
matches = c.matches()
for match in matches:
    if match['mchstate'] != 'nextlive':
            col= (c.commentary(match['id']))
            for my_str in col['commentary']:
                current_game3["commentary2"] = my_str.replace('<br/>', '\n')
                commentary1.append(current_game3)
                current_game3 = {}
for comment in commentary1:
    print(comment['commentary2'])
```

Partial Output:

> Preview by Tristan Lavalette
>
> The Twenty20 tri-series decider between Australia and New Zealand is
>   set to finish with a bang at the tiny Eden Park on Wednesday (February
>   21), as another bout of belligerent batting is expected in Auckland.
>
> In a preview of the final, the teams clashed at Eden Park last Friday
>   and produced a run-fest with the rampaging Australia successfully
>   chasing down a record target of 244. The unbeaten Australia head into
>   the final as favourites after a dazzling campaign from their new look
>   side brimming with in-form Big Bash League players and headed by
>   skipper David Warner, whose inventive captaincy has been
>   inspirational.
>
> Astoundingly, Australia is on the brink of leapfrogging into the No.1
>   T20 ranking having started the tournament a lowly No.7. A victory
>   would be their sixth straight in the format equalling their best ever
>   streak.

Comment: I think he only wants a single newline after each paragraph. Also, it isn't clear whether each current game dictionary will have only 1 commentary.

Comment: @SamCraig, you're right. I'll edit this answer after he clarifies those 2 points. If my answer matches yours after the edit, I'll delete mine.

Comment: You should leave it up. Your answer is a slightly different approach, there isn't any reason why both shouldn't be visible.

Comment: @SamCraig you're right I want a newline after each paragraph and dictionary have one comment for iteration.

Comment: Then use `<br/><br/>` instead of `<br/>` inside replace.

Comment: is there any way possible to edit before appending to commentary1?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Check the edit. `my_str.replace('<br/>', '\n')` will take care of that.